# instead of images blob is showing in oracle

Tags: oracle, image, blob

i have created a table containing name blob_demo

```
rank(int) photo(BLOB)
```

i have inserted data into it and when i try to get the data using "select * from blob_demo" it is showing int in place of int but in place of blob it is not showing image it is just showing (blob).

```
  1                      (BLOB)   
  2                      (BLOB)      
  3                      (BLOB)
```

can you please help me to show image in oracle 11g

Comment: that is the way tools show `blob` data. They are obvious.

Comment: _"it is not showing image"_ What is "it"?

Comment: @Ravi then,is there any other way to display image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you running your query?

If it's with SQL Developer, click in the (blob) cell - you should get a pencil/edit icon. Click that. Then click to view the blob as an image.

[image]

Note that your blob picture might not actually be The Blob, but it should still work.

Comment: do you mean to click on the script output (or) in table edit,i can't get it.can you please explain

Comment: i don't get any edit there can you please explain where to click?

Comment: @prabhur run a query that returns a BLOB with F9, so you get the spreadsheet-like grid back

Comment: i have another doubt can you solve it ?
the question is i am not getting in jdbc in eclipse kepler version ,instead of image it is showing " oracle.sql.BLOB@19f379 " when i use ResultSet.getBlob() method how to image in that eclipse console also?

Comment: @prabhur sorry, no idea - best to ask this as as separate question so an Eclipse maestro can help you

Comment: ok, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Tools, such as SQL*Plus, TOAD, SQL Developer and similar can't do that (as far as I can tell).

You'll have to use a tool which is capable of displaying images out of a BLOB column. For example, Oracle Application Express is one of them - you'd write an application which queries that table and displays images.

If you register on apex.oracle.com (it is free), you'll get access to a pre-installed application which shows how to do that; it is rather simple & straightforward, using the Wizard.

Or, you could use Oracle Forms or Reports (though, these tools are somewhat *oldfashined* these days). Certainly there are other tools capable of displaying images, but I've never used them so I can't suggest anything.

Comment: Nah, SQLDev can do it - just one BLOB at a time though. https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-quick-tip-blobs-and-images/

Comment: Which is A LOT more than nothing; didn't know that, thank you, @thatJS

Comment: you can also setup file associations and launch adobe for PDFs or Excel for your spreadsheets if that's what you're storing in the DB...Codd forbid

Comment: hahahah! It appears that I should catch up with what SQL Developer offers; I knew it since it was *Project Raptor*, but company I work for uses TOAD so I'm more used to use it. Home SQL Dev usage can't compare to vast hours spent at work, so I learn something new almost every day.

Comment: be the hero - convert your company, save them some $$$, use that bonus to buy yourself something nice :)